# SQL - select only one specific type

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know if it's possible to select data with one exact statement.

Lets say I got 2 customers in my database, both of them got the value "1", but one of them has also a value called "2".

How can I get a result with only customer number 1? I'm interested to get all customers who **only** has the value "1", not "1", "2", "3" etc.

More specific description:

```
**Customer 1:**
Name: "Peter"
Value: "1"

**Customer 2:**
Name: "Chris"
Value: "1", "2", "3"
```

Now, I only want a result with Customer 1, who has the value "1"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.value = 1 and 
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.value <> 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `COUNT`, e.g.:

```
SELECT Name
FROM customer
WHERE Value = "1"
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(Value)) = 1;
```